# Data Structure Comparison

Tags: data-structures

I am looking for an aggregated summary of comparison of popular data structures. Kind of one place where i can see all the data structures with their complexities, advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_structures

It compares a few of them, but there are a lot of different structures.

Comment: this link doesn't work anymore

Comment: It looked like that article contained a lot of mistakes. For example, it said insertion into a sorted linked list was O(1), while, in reality, it's O(n)